# css pseudo element extends to whole page width for all screen size

Tags: html, css

[image]

```css
.latest_pagination{
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
.latest_pagination ul{
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
.latest_pagination ul::after{
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 top: 50%;
 left: 100%;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 width:100% ;
}
.latest_pagination ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative; 
 margin-right: 6px;
}
.latest_pagination ul li a{
 color: #666;
 font-size: 24px;
 border: 1px solid #888;
 font-weight: 700;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 45px;
 height: 45px;
 line-height: 45px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
}
.latest_pagination ul li:first-child a,.latest_pagination ul li:last-child a{
 font-size: 18px;
}
.latest_pagination ul li:first-child{
 margin-right: 26px;
}
.latest_pagination ul li:last-child{
 margin-left: 26px;
 margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="latest_pagination">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">0</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want two lines from left right to extend to the full width.
I want the blue line to extend to full page width for all devices.I tampered with width: calc(100% + fixed width) but its not working for all devices.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide with an image defining the out you want.?

Comment: sure..i added a picture..click the "enter image description here" link on the top of this post ...or u can run the code snippet ..thanks!

Comment: I have put an answer please do check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated***

**This will work fine for you.**

I have added some CSS to your Fiddle.

for width I have used `vw`*(viewport-width)*

```
 width: 100vw;
```

*for 100% of the screen width*

In your case use `width: calc(100vw - 2px);` that is `width: calc(100vw - left-border+right-border);`

```css
.latest_pagination {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.latest_pagination ul {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
}

.latest_pagination ul::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: calc(100vw - 2px);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.latest_pagination ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 6px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.latest_pagination ul li a {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.latest_pagination ul li:first-child a,
.latest_pagination ul li:last-child a {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.latest_pagination ul li:first-child {
  margin-right: 26px;
}

.latest_pagination ul li:last-child {
  margin-left: 26px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="latest_pagination">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">0</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I hope this was helpfull.

Comment: This works, but i get a scroll .Instead of 100vw when I use 100%, the scroll disappears. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @kas I have updated my answer please check it. Now there is no Scroll.

Comment: for me,the scroll is still there..it disappears when i deduct around 18px instead of 2px

Comment: @kas did you checked my fiddle.? Here there is no scroll.

Comment: sorry for the late reply..yes i did check your fiddle i do get a scroll not on js fiddle but when i use it in my html page  https://snag.gy/kMse3j.jpg

Comment: @kas I have updated the code one more time, please do check it, I have added   `overflow: hidden;` to `.latest_pagination` and it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your line needs to be its own object relative to the entire container for this to work (left 0, not 100%)

```
.latest_pagination .line {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width:100% ;
}
```

and I filled your circles with background white so the line doesn't show through them:

```css
.latest_pagination{
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
.latest_pagination ul{
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
.latest_pagination .line {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 width:100% ;
}
.latest_pagination ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative; 
 margin-right: 6px;
  background: white;
}
.latest_pagination ul li a{
 color: #666;
 font-size: 24px;
 border: 1px solid #888;
 font-weight: 700;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 45px;
 height: 45px;
 line-height: 45px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
}
.latest_pagination ul li:first-child a,.latest_pagination ul li:last-child a{
 font-size: 18px;
}
.latest_pagination ul li:first-child{
 margin-right: 26px;
}
.latest_pagination ul li:last-child{
 margin-left: 26px;
 margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="latest_pagination">
<div class="line"></div>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">0</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">0</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
```

Comment: This works! Except I don't want the line in the number list.So when I add a background it works perfectly. Thank you! Appreciate the help.

Comment: Awesome! Adjust the code now to suit your situation. :)